# Laravel on some kind of Model Ready method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Well i don't know how to format the title of this post in very clear way, but here's my question:

Say i have

```
Posts::find('1);
Photos:find('1');
... and so on, every mode db request
```

now by default i can access db columns, for instance the id: through model->id

```
$Photos = Photos::find('1')->first();
echo $Photos->id; // will return 1
```

what i want is that i need all those kind of requests to add a custom field automatically like hashed_id, which is not in the database, which in return will make all models have a hashed_id as well, i know i can add that field to database and then grab it but i need it for different reasons/implementations

i did create a BaseModel and every Model will extend that BaseModel, so Photos extends BaseModel, BaseModel extends Model... and all that etc etc.

but i need some kind of constructor, upon retrieving data to process the data automatically without having to add -let's say- a hash_id() after retrieving the data.

something like, onAfterGet(), onReady()....sort of commands.

i hope my question is clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `Accessor`. Accesors can be used to add custom attributes to the model. Combine this with the `$appends` property and you have exactly what you need. The `$appends` property adds the custom accessor in every result.

You can do this by creating a base model like you've stated in the question or by using traits. I'll show you an example on how to achieve this using a base model.

Let's create  base model called `BaseModel`. All other models that need this custom attribute will extend this.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['hashed_id'];

    public function getHashedIdAttribute()
    {
        return some_hash_function($this->id);
    }
}
```

We have a `Image` model which extends our `BaseModel`.

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Image extends BaseModel
{

}
```

Now every result from the `Image` model will have the `hashed_id` field added by default.

Accesor documenation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, all you need to do is to define [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator), for example:

```
<?php
class Photo extends Model
{
    /* ... model implementation ... */

    public function getHashedIdAttribute()
    {
        return md5($this->id);
    }
}
```

Then you can access property like it was in database:

```
echo Photo::find(5)->hashed_id;
```